# MySQL Partitioning Error - Error Code : 1486

Tags: mysql

MySQL throwing error while creating partitions on table.

Error Code : 1486
Constant, random or timezone-dependent expressions in (sub)partitioning function are not allowed.

I have tried following query :

```
 alter table test.tbl1 
 partition by range(unix_timestamp(sys_time))
(
PARTITION p20151001 VALUES LESS THAN (unix_timestamp('2015-10-01')),
PARTITION p20151101 VALUES LESS THAN (unix_timestamp('2015-11-01')),
PARTITION p20151201 VALUES LESS THAN (unix_timestamp('2015-12-01')),
PARTITION p20160101 VALUES LESS THAN (unix_timestamp('2016-01-01')),
PARTITION p20160201 VALUES LESS THAN (unix_timestamp('2016-02-01')),
PARTITION p20160301 VALUES LESS THAN (unix_timestamp('2016-03-01'))
);
```

How can I round this problem. 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading here it may be possible that you are using MYSQL 5.1:

https://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql_55_partitioning.html

> Another pain point in MySQL 5.1 is the handling of date columns. You
>   can't use them directly, but you need to convert such columns using
>   either YEAR or TO_DAYS

If your column `sys_time` is a `DATETIME`, you dont need to specify the timestamp in order to partition it, you just need to do `TO_DAYS`, since you're not doing it by year:

```
alter table test.tbl1 
partition by range (TO_DAYS(sys_time))
(
PARTITION p20151001 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2015-10-01')),
PARTITION p20151101 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2015-11-01')),
PARTITION p20151201 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2015-12-01')),
PARTITION p20160101 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2016-01-01')),
PARTITION p20160201 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2016-02-01')),
PARTITION p20160301 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2016-03-01'))
);
```

if sys_time is a `TIMESTAMP` then you dont need to convert your timestamp to a timestamp, I have taken that out of the range parameter:

```
 alter table test.tbl1 
 partition by range(sys_time)
(
PARTITION p20151001 VALUES LESS THAN (unix_timestamp('2015-10-01')),
PARTITION p20151101 VALUES LESS THAN (unix_timestamp('2015-11-01')),
PARTITION p20151201 VALUES LESS THAN (unix_timestamp('2015-12-01')),
PARTITION p20160101 VALUES LESS THAN (unix_timestamp('2016-01-01')),
PARTITION p20160201 VALUES LESS THAN (unix_timestamp('2016-02-01')),
PARTITION p20160301 VALUES LESS THAN (unix_timestamp('2016-03-01'))
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but `sys_time` is of type `datetime`.

Comment: Now I am getting this error: `1697
VALUES value for partition 'p20151001' must have type INT`

Comment: is `sys_time` a datetime, or is it actually a timestamp? datetime is `2015-01-01 00:00:00` timestamp is `23423432442`

Comment: it's a datetime field.

Comment: Have you take the `unix_timestamp` out of this line : `partition by range columns(sys_time)`

Comment: Hi Octopi, Thank you so much for your answer. I have just replaced `unix_timestamp` with `to_days` and it is works fine now.